# How to reach out to a company to ask questions about a job posting?

Tags: job-search, applications, job-description

Sometimes companies provide an email or a name of a person within the company who can be contacted to either submit the job application or to ask questions about the job posting.

A lot of the time, however, this is not the case, especially for big companies. I do, however, sometimes have questions about the job posting, the answers to which would directly impact my decision of whether or not I will apply for the job.

How do I go about reaching out to the company to ask questions about the job posting when no contact information is provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When posting without contact information the assumption is usually the application coming before a phone screen where the candidate can ask questions about whether or not to continue with the process. It might seem backwards but it saves the recruiters time by filtering contact only to interested candidates.

So the best way to ask questions about those job postings is to apply and wait for a recruiter to contact you. You can also try hitting up a recruiter on LinkedIn but chances are it will not be as effective.

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, I usually contact some people with good titles working on the target company via LinkedIn. They can redirect you to the right person.